# Realm RLMArray is nil

Tags: objective-c, realm

For some reason my RLMArray's are nil when I run my program.
I am able to see the data in the RLM browser, and it links appropriatley.

Is there something I could be missing here?

```
@interface HMFAlbum : RLMObject

@property NSInteger persistentId;

@property RLMArray<HMFTrack> *tracks;
@property RLMArray<HMFRange> *ranges;

@end

@interface HMFTrack : RLMObject

@property NSInteger persistentId;
@property HMFAlbum *album;

@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(HMFTrack)

@interface HMFRange : RLMObject

@property NSInteger persistentId;
@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *albums;

@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(HMFRange)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you seeing nil values in your program? Are you looking at an instance variable in a debugger, printing out the object’s description, printing out the value returned when accessing the property, or doing something else entirely?

Comment: Debugger shows nil.
If I ask for Album.tracks.count I get the correct value. But if I do Album.tracks.firstObject I get a blank object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expected that instance variables of persisted `RLMObject` instances will be `nil` as the property getters read values directly from the Realm file. The instance variables are only used for objects prior to being saved to the Realm, and remain `nil` after that point.

The [Debugging](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#debugging) section of the Realm documentation touches on this topic and mentions an LLDB script that can be used to show property values of persisted objects when debugging in Xcode. The `-description` method on the model classes, used by `NSLog` when formatting objects using the `%@` format specifier, will also show the property values as expected.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. I guess my problem is that I have some data that needs to be loaded that is not stored in the db. For instance, my track objects store a path to a file on disk. I load the title, artist, etc. from the asset file.

Comment: I’m not sure why that would be a problem. If I understood your initial problem correctly, it is simply a display issue in he debugger rather than an actual problem with your application’s behavior.